# Calculating probability that a certain amount of time goes by without the event occurring

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Can anybody help me with this question that I stumbled upon in my statistics book today?

> Mia breaks glasses at the rate of four per week.Let T be the time, in weeks, between successive breakages of glasses. Then, $f(t)=4e^{-4t}$ for $t\geq0$. What is the probability that a week goes by without Mia breaking any glasses?

I know I'm supposed to use integration to find the probability, I just dont know how to go about this question.
Any help with this question would be much appreciated!

Comment: Integrate $f(t)$ with respect to $t$ to get $F(t)$, choosing the constant $C$ such that $F(0) = 0$.  Then evaluate $F(t)$ at the proper value of $t$.

Comment: But that doesn't get me the probability. How do I find the rpobability? Don't I need to find the area under the probability distribution function $f(t)$? I just don't know how what intervals to use, because I cant calculate the probability for just one one value

Comment: @BrianTung's hint **does** give you a probability. See my Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow @BrianTung's Comment to obtain the CDF of $T,$
which is $F_T(t) = 1 - e^{-4t},$ for $t > 0.$
Then the probability that a given week goes by
without Mia breaking a glass is $P(T > 1) = 1 - P(T\le 1).$

In R, an exponential density function is `dexp` and an
exponential CDF is `pexp`, where the parameter for your problem is rate $\lambda = 4.$

```
1 - pexp(1, 4)
[1] 0.01831564
```

In the left panel of the figure below, the desired area is to the right of $1$ under the
density curve. The CDF is shown in the right panel.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 curve(dexp(x, 4), 0, 2, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", 
       main="Density of EXP(rate = 4)")
  abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
  abline(v = 1, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 curve(pexp(x,4), 0, 2, lwd=2, ylab="CDF", 
       main="CDF of Exp(rate-4)")
  abline(v=1, col="green2"); abline(h=0:1, col="green2")
  abline(h = 1, lwd=1, lty="dotted")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!